# arrays are static data structure . Then how can memory be allocated to them dynamically?

Tags: c, pointers

A static datatype is one which is having fixed size in memory. As we declare the array size in advance, that much bytes or space is reserved in memory and cannot be increased later. So this way an array is a Static datatype.

OK. but we can dynamically allocate memory to arrays using pointers or an array of pointers. I don't get the whole concept clearly. Please help

Comment: Author is trying to speak about two concepts static array and dynamic array(pointers)

Comment: Is your a question or a quotation from somewhere else (since you post it as quotation)? Please specify and edit in the case.

Comment: Array like this: `char arr[10];` can't be dynamically allocated, but when you use pointers `char *arr;` you can dynamically allocate memory to your array. they are two differents things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concepts are:

```
// example 1
int array1[256];  // a fixed size, global array of 256 ints, statically allocated

void example2(void)
{
    int array2[256];  // an array of fixed size 256, allocated when the function is entered
    //...
    //...             // and automatically released (deallocated) when the function exits
}

void example3(int n)
{
    int array3[n];    // an array of fixed size n, allocated when the function is entered
    //...
    //...             // and automatically released (deallocated) when the function exits
}

void example4(int n)
{
    int *array4;
    array4= malloc(n*sizeof(int));  // a dynamically allocated array
    //...
    free(array4);  // that must be manually deallocated when no longer needed
}
```

In the 1st example, the size of the array is determined at compile time and is fixed during the execution of the program. The array resides in global memory during the whole execution of the program.

In the 2nd example, the size of the array is also determined at compile time and remains fixed during the execution of the program, but the memory is allocated on the stack when the function is entered. So in a recursive function more than one occurence of this array can exist at the same time.

The 3rd example uses variable sized arrays of later C standards (VLAs). The array size is fixed during execution of the function but can change at each function invocation. If `n` is large, then you can easily run out of stack space, causing the program to crash.

The 4th example dynamically allocates arrays from the heap, using pointers. By reallocating the array, its size can change also during the invocation of the function. The heap is often much larger than the stack so for large arrays this method is prefered. Because the array does not reside on the stack, you can return it to a caller (who must then take care to free it when no longer needed).

Comment: Add that the example3 allocates the space on the stack which is usually much smaller the the heap.

Comment: THANKU SO MUCH,IT HELPED ME A LOT . SO I CAN DEFINE ARRAYS AS STATIC DATATYPE WHICH CAN BE ALLOCATED MEMORY AT COMPILE TIME(STATIC FIXED MEMORY ALLOCATION) AND ALSO DYNAMICALLY (AT RUNTIME ALSO)

Comment: Amit, just try the concepts a bit, then start using them as needed.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you are having some difficulties in understanding the difference between array and dynamic memory.

Whenever you declare an array, for example:

```
char array[10];
```

You are allocating 10 `chars` (so most of the time 10 bytes) in the stack.

But a program does not only have the stack to allocate data, but also the heap. Since the size of an array is known at compilation time, this can be already allocated. But what happens if the quantity of memory is unknown at compilation and need to be allocated dynamically? Then you can allocate the required memory in the heap and have the pointer in the stack. For example:

```
char *ptr;
```

Allocates the pointer in stack, and aftewards you can allocate the required memory in the heap, by using malloc (or calloc):

```
ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof (char));
```

This will allocate 10 bytes of memory in the heap.

On one side arrays are freed automatically when the stack is released, on the other side the memory allocated in the heap has to be explicitly released, or you can have memory leakage.

Another note is that, when running multiple threads, each thread has its own stack, but they all share the same heap. While when running multiple processes, each process has its own stack and heap.

Comment: "10 chars (so most of the time 10 bytes)" -- 1 `char` always has a size of 1 byte in C, by definition, and arrays can't contain padding. Stacks and heaps are implementation details, not C language details.

Comment: _"You are allocating 10 chars (so most of the time 10 bytes) in the stack"_ It depends where the declaration is (inside a function, or outside of functions). And _"...the stack is released"_ is somewhat fishy. A local array is freed upon function exit.

Comment: @DavidBowling yep that is true, just didn't come in my mind when I was writing. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes I agree, arrays are on the stack if declared in the function! I gave that for granted.